# How can I get pytest to ignore Test* classes that don't subclass unittest?

Tags: python, pytest

I'm trying to get tests for [testfixtures](https://github.com/Simplistix/testfixtures) passing with pytest, but it keeps trying to collect things that aren't tests:

```
======================================================= pytest-warning summary ========================================================
WC1 /Users/chris/vcs/git/testfixtures/testfixtures/tests/test_comparison.py cannot collect test class 'TestClassA' because it has a __init__ constructor
WC1 /Users/chris/vcs/git/testfixtures/testfixtures/tests/test_components.py cannot collect test class 'TestComponents' because it has a __init__ constructor
WC1 /Users/chris/vcs/git/testfixtures/testfixtures/tests/test_datetime.py cannot collect test class 'TestTZInfo' because it has a __new__ constructor
WC1 /Users/chris/vcs/git/testfixtures/testfixtures/tests/test_datetime.py cannot collect test class 'TestTZ2Info' because it has a __new__ constructor
cannot collect test class 'TestContainer' because it has a __init__ constructor
cannot collect test class 'TestTZInfo' because it has a __new__ constructor
```

How can I get pytest to only collect Test* classes that subclass unittest.TestCase?

Answer (score 16):

I found this in the Pytest [2.6 release notes](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/changelog.html#id155):

> support nose-style `__test__` attribute on modules, classes and functions, including unittest-style Classes. If set to False, the test will not be collected.

This can help if your class *is* being collected when you don't want it to be, but it doesn't help with the "cannot collect test class because it has a `__init__` constructor" warning.

Comment: This doesn't work on the released versions of pytest for classes that don't subclass unittest.TestCase

Comment: Oh my God, I've checked the whole Internet for this answer.

Comment: @ChrisWithers - is this still true? In my case using \__test\__ worked.

Comment: I suspect so, my guess is 2.6 hadn't been released when I made my comment.

Comment: It works (upvoted), and pytest 2.6 was released in [Jul 2014](https://pypi.org/project/pytest/2.6.0/#files) 3 years before this Q&A.

Answer (score 5):

Pytest uses glob-style name patterns to collect tests, and the discovery can be customized by the options `python_files`, `python_classes`, and `python_functions` in the configuration file.

The [defaults are like this](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/238b25ffa9d4acbc7072ac3dd6d8240765643aed/src/_pytest/python.py#L108-L126):

```
[pytest]
python_files=test_*.py *_test.py
python_classes=Test
python_functions=test
```

Perhaps you could just customize it not to collect classes by overriding that:

```
# pytest.ini (or in tox.ini, or in setup.cfg)
[pytest]  # if using setup.cfg, this section name should instead be [tool:pytest]
python_classes=NoThanks
```

*Note:* it's not limited to one pattern here, you may specify a list of them.

**Classes which inherit `unittest.TestCase` should still be collected regardless of this option**.  This is because the unittest framework itself is used to collect those tests.

Comment: I think this should be the answer. @Chris_Withers, you don't think so?

Comment: Note: To disable the name-based feature entirely just use `python_classes=`

Answer (score 2):

You can also just run pytest with the following flag:

```
-W ignore::pytest.PytestCollectionWarning
```