# How to prevent PytestCollectionWarning when testing class Testament via pytest

Tags: python, pytest

**Update to more general case:**
How can I prevent a PytestCollectionWarning when testing a Class Testament via pytest? Simple example for testament.py:

```
class Testament():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def check(self):
        return True
```

And the test_testament.py

```
from testament.testament import Testament

def test_send():
    testament = Testament("Paul")

    assert testament.check()
```

This creates a PytestCollectionWarning when run with pytest. Is there a way to suppress this warning for the imported module without turning all warnings off?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42268401/how-can-i-get-pytest-to-ignore-test-classes-that-dont-subclass-unittest?

Comment: @Suzana I don't think its the same issue. My problem here has nothing to do with subclassing unittest.TestCase (at least as far as I understood; I do not use unittest at all).

Comment: I created a feature request for pytest, but it seems not possible: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/6418 For now, the only solution seems to be some kind of workaround (e.g. as descibed in answers by @Suzana and @Éric)

Comment: The other question was about classes that *don't* subclass unittest.TestCase but still start with Test... so that they get (falsely) collected by pytest. I think that's the same problem.

Comment: @Suzana: I'm not sure, if I understand this. The linked question was: "How can I get pytest to only collect Test* classes that subclass unittest.TestCase?" Thats not what I wanted (or does pytest internally subclass unittest.TestCase?).

Comment: @natter1 no, the linked question is "How can I get pytest to ignore Test* classes that don't subclass unittest?" But the problem is the same, classes that start with "Test" are collected even though they are not even in the specified test directory.

Comment: @Suzana - You quote the title, I quote from question text - but for both cases, at least I wouldn't have expected an answer to my question there - for me its something different, because I do not want to ignore (all) classes not subclassing unittest.TestCase (I allready knew, I could use ignore::pytest.PytestCollectionWarning or change the search-pattern for that; maybe I should have added the "without turning all warnings off" part in the title). But at least, the correct answer for my problem is also there (even if I overlooked it, because a comment stated, it would not work).

Comment: I don't care, if this becomes marked as duplicate, but than make sure the answer with __test__ and the missleading(?) comment by Chris Withers is handled somehow

Comment: Okay then I wouldn't mark it as a duplicate even though the two questions should be linked IMO. I think the real problem is that if pytest is called for example with test directory test/unit, and those tests import files from src that start with "Test", these should not be considered test classes because they are not in the test directory.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can set a `__test__ = False` attribute in classes that pytest should ignore:

```
class Testament:
    __test__ = False
```

Comment: I comment, because this is marked as an answer. I think following post provides a much cleaner solution (and not a workaround) https://stackoverflow.com/a/42281313/6702598 Reasoning: Your `Testament` should not know about tests.  @natter1 maybe consider changing the accepted answer? Or accept the duplication issue so people get redirected.

Comment: this is not ideal. you should not add testing configuration into code that ships to production. pytest comes with a lot of settings that should be sufficient to configure outside of production code

Answer (score 4):

You can run pytest with the following flag:

```
-W ignore::pytest.PytestCollectionWarning
```

This is just the "normal" warning filter for python, according to the [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html):

> Both -W command-line option and filterwarnings ini option are based on Python’s own -W option and warnings.simplefilter

Comment: The problem with this solution is, that it might also turn off some useful warnings - I don't want to do that. Its similar to catching BaseException - its easy at first, but might bite you when you least expect it.

Comment: Yes, except that you will encounter a lot of BaseExceptions but the probability that PytestCollectionWarning might also tell me something useful is rather low...

Answer (score 1):

You can define the [python_classes](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#confval-python_classes) option in your config file to change from default `Test*` to e.g. `*Tests`.